# Is it necessary to recreate this game in pygame on the backend to make this frontend game multiplayer?

Tags: python, html, canvas, pygame

I found this game: https://github.com/JDStraughan/html5-lightcycles/blob/master/main.js

And I decided i wanted to make it a multiplayer browser game. I've just finished building the lobby and I'm struggling on where to start when it comes to copying this game on the backend. The backend is python and im using websockets. The game I linked uses the canvas element. I asked elsewhere and they said I should look into using pygame, but I think that is overkill. What exactly do i need to be copying on the backend? Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not quite need py game, it is simple and no graphics will be done on the backend. Just use a bit of any language your server can handle. Maybe some OO python or java. The netcode would be the hardest part.

Comment: what exactly will I be copying? each user's coordinate history and checking collisions?

Comment: The server acts as the model, which simulates the entire game in real time. The browser JavaScript is simply the view. It gets the position of every object from the server periodically and draws to a canvas. So the whole game logic runs on the server, and the graphics runs in the browser.

Comment: Just make sure the game creator is OK with you copying his/her game.

Comment: Right, it's tron lightcycles. By the time I'm done the code will likely be different, I'm just using his code as a base. I'll get in contact with him though

Comment: Html5 has the canvas element with which movements are made on the frontend. How will I run this game logic on the backend?

Comment: You should learn about game programming if you have never done it. But you can probably just port the JS to python or something else. Basically you have a game loop which updates the state of the game a certain number of times per second. The backend does not need any graphics.

Comment: Then send the game state to all the listening clients. This forum is not the place for broad topics like this, but you can find lots of information about running a server online.